# Infragistics Grid: Using DataSet binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, infragistics

I am working on a project to create a hierarchical grid, but first I want to get the initial dataset to render.  I am working straight from the example that Infragistics provided on the subject.

My Controller:

```
public class BatchingController : Controller

    {
        DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
        private int currentUser = Lt.GetThisUsersCoId();

        [GridDataSourceAction]
        [ActionName("BatchList")]
        public ActionResult BatchList()
        {
            var ds = new DataSet("List");
            DataTable batchTable = BatchListDataTable();

            ds.Tables.Add(batchTable);

            return View("BatchList", ds);
        }

        private DataTable BatchListDataTable()
        {
            var contex = new LBPEntities();
            var dtData = new DataTable();
            dtData.Columns.Add("BatchNumber");
            dtData.Columns.Add("BatchGroupItemDate");
            dtData.Columns.Add("BatchComment");
            dtData.Columns.Add("NumberOfDocuments");
            dtData.Columns.Add("TotalTransfered");
            dtData.Columns.Add("NotTransfered");
            dtData.Columns.Add("CoId");

            DataRow row = null;
            var buildBatchList = (from x in contex.vwBatchLists
                                  where x.CoId == currentUser
                select x);

            foreach (var rowObj in buildBatchList)
            {
                row = dtData.NewRow();
                dtData.Rows.Add(rowObj.BatchNumber
                    , rowObj.BatchGroupItemDate
                    , rowObj.BatchComment
                    , rowObj.NumberOfDocuments
                    , rowObj.TotalTransfered
                    , rowObj.NotTransfered
                    , rowObj.CoId);
            }

            dtData.PrimaryKey = new[] { dtData.Columns["BatchNumber"] };
            return dtData;
        }
    }
```

My View:

```
@using Infragistics.Web.Mvc
@using System.Data

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined CSS Files -->
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/igniteui/css/themes/infragistics/infragistics.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/igniteui/css/structure/infragistics.css")" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/modernizr.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/jquery-ui.min.js")"></script>

    <!-- Ignite UI Required Combined JavaScript Files -->
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/igniteui/js/infragistics.core.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/igniteui/js/infragistics.lob.js")"></script>

</head>
<body>

    @(Html.Infragistics().Grid<System.Data.DataSet>()
        .ID("grid1")
        .Width("100%")
        .DefaultColumnWidth("150px")
        .AutoGenerateColumns(true)
        .AutoGenerateLayouts(true)
        .Features(features =>
        {
            features.Sorting().Type(OpType.Local).Mode(SortingMode.Single).Inherit(true);
            features.Paging().PageSize(5).Type(OpType.Remote).Inherit(false);
            features.Filtering().Type(OpType.Local).Inherit(true);
            features.Selection().Mode(SelectionMode.Row).MultipleSelection(true);
            features.GroupBy().Type(OpType.Local).Inherit(true);
            features.Hiding().Inherit(true);
        })
        .DataSource(Model)
        .DataSourceUrl(Url.Action("BatchList"))
        .DataBind()
        .Render()
    )
</body>
</html>
```

I am receiving an error which says "Data source must implement IQueryable." However the project they provide is structured the same way by passing a DataSet to the view, and no such error is thrown.

When running the code and inspecting the model, I can see that my dataset is indeed populated with what I'm looking for:
[image]

I must be missing something fundamental.  My understanding is that it will build the grid right from the dataset that I am passing it. However I cannot find where they declared any other model that is referenced and any place where they set the column names. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your assumption is quite right - the grid can generate columns/layouts from the data set and you don't need extra models. It's actually kind of weird, because your code works anyways: http://sdrv.ms/19M9CEm 
The only reason I can think of for getting that error is the Model passed to the view (which is used as data source) is wrong/missing - not the data set, then by default IQueryable is expected.
Perhaps try putting a breakpoint at the helpers location in the view and inspect the Model.If you are still experiencing issues, can you share what version are you using and a sample for the issue.